# Node.JS Express data transfer

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, request

I am attempting to transfer data back and forth from one node.js instance to the other.

I am using express and request to transfer this data, I just started this specific project and it's not exactly going as well as id like to admit.

**Here is my main application that receives the post request.**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('POST request to the homepage');
console.log('POST REQUEST' + res + req);
});

var server = app.listen(3004, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

**Here is my node instance 2 that is acting as the client.**

```
var request = require('request');

request.post(
    'http://192.168.1.225:3004',
    { form: { key: 'notyourmother' } },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    }
);
```

When running this, this is the response I get, later once it works it will be assigned to a variable as a string. At this moment it wont even give me the data I sent via the post, i used request and response to see which pipe the data flowed in on the console.log

[image]

My end goal is to be able to send commands to the server with http post and request.

If anyone has any advice it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by 'it won't give me the data'. How do you get it?

Comment: You probably want express body-parser middleware.

Comment: Is this the proper way to transfer data like this? It seems im having to do a lot of uncessecary things to transfer a simple string across a node.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right, you basically get your data in `req`(which is the request object). In a post the data is in body as `req.body`.

Basically if you change your line `res.send('POST request to the homepage');` to `res.send('POST request to the homepage' + req.body);`you should see your string as well in your client.

Normally, you want to have the body-parser ( https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser ) Which you could integrate in your app as follows

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('POST request to the homepage');
console.log('POST REQUEST' + res + req);
});

var server = app.listen(3004, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Remember, if you are posting json that the client should send the header `content-type: application/json` to the server.

Comment: DevAlien, Thank you for your response. Sent me a little more on track.
Still having an issue with the request popping up like its supposed to.
With your code + the req.body and the module, i get the same response that i did earlier in the thread.

Comment: Cool, dont forget to vote or set the answer as the right one, if it is. It is good for others as well.

Comment: Trying to figure out how to share my code with you again, I get the 
"POST REQUEST[object Object][object Object]" from the server console still

Comment: Even with the req.body and the package in there

Comment: Yes because it gets transformed as a string. Instead of sending `+ req.body`. You can access the json object. `+ req.bidy.form.key`

Comment: What might be happening now?

TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined
    at /twitterbot/server.js:12:44
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/twitterbot/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/twitterbot/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/twitterbot/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)

Comment: This is my client again

var request = require('request');

request.post(
    'http://192.168.1.225:3007',
    { form: { key: 'notyourmother' } },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    }
);

Comment: We cannot go ahead with comments. But use a console.log of req.body and check ( it will appear on the server log )